# How can I move my kitchen sink drain 18 inches?

Tags: concrete, kitchens, drain, slab

I am doing a kitchen renovation and am having a hard time finding a plumber.

I am looking to move the kitchen sink that's at a 45 degree angle to no angle requiring me to move the drain line about 12-18 inches. If I don't move the drain line it will be exposed in the flooring in front of the new sink.

This is in Florida so the house is built on a concrete slab. I dug out a trench and exposed the drain line. It had a sweep 90 elbow off the straight drain pipe and came straight under the sink in the concrete. I need to move it 90 degrees horizontally (with a 1/4 inch/ft slope) the 12-18 inches and then straight up.

Can I use 2 90 degree sweep elbows or should I use a 45 elbow with maybe a 10 inch straight pipe to another 45 elbow and then a short straight piece and then into the 90 sweep elbow straight up through the floor?

In the pic, the drain needs to be moved where the PEX lines are towards the laminate floors on the top of the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a lot of work and simply move the cabinets out a few inches. This will give you more horizontal surface on the top which you can always use. This way the drain will be hidden. I have done this with our 4 seasons room, laundry, and kitchen. Our friends comment on this all the time saying they wish they had done this. We also placed 2x4s flat and put our cabinets on top of them, makes the counter a bit higher which we like as it is harder to bend as we age.

Comment: So are you creating a larger than usual overhang in the BACK of your cabinets and custom-making the counter to that depth?  Does the back edge of the counter need additional support from the wall?

Comment: For me it was easy to put a 2x4 back there and attach it to the wall, the gap is only 6" so no problem. This also helps anchor the cabinets when the top is put in place.   The top changes in size but the finishing is the same.  I used Quartz in the kitchen and baths, it was no problem as it was cut from a much larger sheet. In my lab i used formica and again it was no problem it had to be cut anyway and I had less waste Both were priced by the Sq foot, not by dimensions.

Comment: Since cabinets are usually attached to the wall through their backs, this seems to create an issue for that. Also, it seems that upper cabinets (likely for a kitchen remodel) would be harder to reach or would also have to be furred out from the wall. Finally, this costs floor space, which isn't cheap in every home. (12" of floor space lost in the kitchen of my 1890s home would be near catastrophic!)

Comment: So the kitchen sink and the other cabinet in line with the sink and dishwasher are the dividing point between the kitchen and the family room. There's only a 3 foot wall behind the sink/dishwasher and other cabinet. We are also putting an island in the middle of the kitchen and cannot move the cabinets out further.....is moving the drain 12 inches and having 2 45 elbows going to cause clogs/drainage issues?

Answer (score 0):

> can I use 2 90 degree sweep elbows or should I use a 45 elbow with maybe a 10 inch straight pipe to another 45 elbow and then a short straight piece and then into the 90 sweep elbow straight up through the floor?

It seems that extending the plumbing straight from whichever direction the line runs under the floor will not get you to where you need it. So, use whatever combination of elbows (sweeps are better than sharp corners in a horizontal run) that it will take to get the horizontal line where you need it. They even make 22.5° elbows in case you need more precise direction changes. Be sure to maintain your 1/4" fall per 1' run slope to ensure drainage (as you already know).

From there, use a 90° elbow or sweep to transition to vertical. If it doesn't come out *exactly* where you need it, that's not a problem, standard P-traps are adjustable for precisely this reason.